# Setup Wifi proxy credentials programmatically

Tags: java, android, proxy

The app will be signed with the system signature, so in the end some protected permissions (like android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS) may be granted.

My question is then how to setup credentials globally for a proxy on a particular WiFi network knowing that the app will be signed with system signature?

I can't find any information on how to do this. Based on what can be done in a standard java app, the following code may work :

```
        System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", usr);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", pwd);
```

But, is it the way to set proxy credentials on Android ? Is it going to set proxy credentials globally (i.e. for all apps using default http support) ? (IMO, even if this call works it won't change anything outside process boundary)

I also checked the code of [android.provider.Settings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings) where I found some properties about global proxy : `global_http_proxy_host` and `global_http_proxy_port` but nothing about proxy authentication.

Comment: Well, I have no clue about Android, but I already faced that kind of problem in a pure java application : authenticate user on an http proxy. What I've done is subclass the standard java.net.Authenticator. to prompt user for a login / password. From what I see, Android provides similar case : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html

Comment: You are interested in changing the same for your app or for the phone?

Comment: The goal is to change it for the phone globally. Or at least for all apps using the default http support provided by the Android-SDK. The goal is to obtain the same result as when you enter manually a proxy username/password through the Settings>Wifi>Select a network>Advanced>Proxy

Comment: The corresponding API to the manual method is [WifiConfiguration.setHttpProxy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#setHttpProxy(android.net.ProxyInfo)). Unfortunately it is only available since 26 and it does not seem to support authentication.

Comment: the global proxy is probably not a good idea to use ; usually the proxy configuration depends on the network (e.g. use proxy from intranet, use no proxy on GSM)

Answer (score 6):

Android uses `System.setSystemProp` to set the proxy in [frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Proxy.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/net/Proxy.java)

I guess you can do the same thing if you have system privileges.

I'm unsure if it affects `android.webkit` though.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to set global proxy credentials in Android. There's simply no structure in the whole AOSP that can hold it.

Unfortunately, I did not manage to find any explanation for this. Relevant Issue Tracker items are not public, comments in the source code are scarce. There's nothing in the developers blog on the issue. Embedded Android by Karim Yaghmour does not shed light on the issue either.

P.S. This answer is based purely on code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify ipconfig.txt file in your /data/misc/wifi directory (actually, directory depends on device model) if you have signature rights. Please refer to readIpAndProxyConfigurations method in [WifiConfigStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfigStore.java). I know that method is quite crude, but it works on my corporate phones. Please note that some phone models may require disabling wifi and restarting wpa_supplicant process after changing ipconfig.txt